# Which case of the master theorem is this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relation

I have a question about the following recurrence relation:

$$T(n) = 27 \cdot T\left(\frac n 3\right ) + n^3 \log n$$

Using the master theorem, will this be

- $T(n) = \Theta(n^3)$, or
- $T(n) = \Theta(n^3 \log \log n)$?

Comment: Plug the possible answers in the recurrence, and you'll know.

Answer (score 1):

If a recurrence relation is of the [form](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html#:%7E:text=FOR%20DIVIDING%20FUNCTIONS-,If%20a%C2%A0Recurrence%20Relation%C2%A0is%20of%20the%20Form,-T)

$$ T(n)=  aT \left( \frac{n}{b} \right) +  {n^k}(\log n)^p $$

then, as per the [Master Theorem](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html), we have *six conditions* depending on
value of $a,b,k$ and $p$

- If $\log_b a>k$ : Answer is $\Theta(n^{\log_b a})$
- If $\log_b a=k$ and $p>1$ :  Answer is $\Theta({n^k}({\log n})^{p+1})$
- If $\log_b a=k$ and $p=1$  : Answer is $\Theta({n^k}\log\log n)$
- If $\log_b a=k$ and $p<1$  : Answer is $\Theta(n^k)$
- If $\log_b a<k$ and $p \geq 0$ : Answer is $\Theta({n^k}({\log n})^p)$
- If $\log_b a<k$ and $p < 0$ : Answer is $\Theta({n^k})$

In any problem, our main motive is to find $a,b,k$ and $p$.

For the problem with

- $a=27$
- $b=3$
- $k=3$
- $p=1$,

$\log_3 27 = 3$, so $\log_b a = k$, and since $p=1$, the answer is
$\Theta({n^k}\log\log n)$

$$\Theta({n^3}\log\log n)$$

Comment: Please don't revert back changes that actually fix math notation.  1. It's $\Theta(\cdot)$ and not $\theta(\cdot)$.  2. It's $\log$ not $log$.  3. Don't use `\bigg` when `\left` will do.  4. $p = 1$, not $p = -1$.

Comment: Thanks for the information @PålGD. Wasn't aware of these.

Answer (score 0):

Quick check:

$$\Theta(n^3)=27\,\Theta\left(\frac{n^3}{27}\right)+n^3\log\log n$$

does not hold.